# Insert a small image(png) on the top right corner of a python plot

Tags: python, image, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I would like to insert a small image(png) on the top right corner inside the frame of the python plot. I am using a very simple code that generates a curve but I would just like to add that small image on the top right corner inside the frame of the plot itself.
thank you very much

Comment: It might be a good idea to supply anything that you may have tried already.

Comment: Duplicate of [putting-a-small-image-on-the-corner-of-a-plot-with-matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25291322/putting-a-small-image-on-the-corner-of-a-plot-with-matplotlib)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to insert a small image on the corner of a plot with matplotlib?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609585/how-to-insert-a-small-image-on-the-corner-of-a-plot-with-matplotlib)